# Save NSView representation ignores transparency

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I am trying to change the icon of a file to a representation of an `NSView`. I am using the following code to do so.

```
    [mainDisplay lockFocus];
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:[mainDisplay bounds]];
    [mainDisplay unlockFocus];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[rep representationUsingType:NSTIFFFileType properties:nil]];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:image forFile:[savePanel filename] options:0];
```

This works. It changes the icon exactly how I would like, except for the fact that any transparency to white. How can I keep the transparency? I know it works for Photoshop, but is is possible using Apple's frameworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get an image with transparency this way, because `[NSBitmapImageRep initWithFocusedViewRect:]` gets a piece of rendered image from the window server, where the view's image already flattened to an image with other underlaying views and the window's background.

What you need is it to allocate a new clean `NSBitmapImageRep` with appropriate format and render the view's content on it:

```
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil 
pixelsWide:[mainDisplay bounds].size.width pixelsHigh:[mainDisplay bounds].size.height
bitsPerSample:8 samplesPerPixel:4 hasAlpha:YES isPlanar:NO
colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
bytesPerRow:[mainDisplay bounds].size.width * 4 bitsPerPixel:32];

[mainDisplay cacheDisplayInRect:[mainDisplay bounds] toBitmapImageRep:rep];
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this immediately. Is there any way to decrease the memory usage of this code (not that it isn't efficient)? EDIT: This is fantastic! Thanks so much! I would definitely like to know of any way to increase the efficiency, but, as my original code wasn't very efficient, it is not necessary.

Comment: Use Instruments to tune the efficiency. Release the `rep` and the `image` right after you have set the icon for the file. Also, try to not autorelease them if you use it in a loop for many files, use normal release.

Comment: You can and should send the view [a `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:`) to create the rep. Besides being easier, the documentation suggests that this is important “for pixel-format compatibility”.