# Convert RGB tiff file to CMYK macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, zxing, core-image, color-space

I have a CGImageRef in RGB obtained from ZXing barcode library, however, I need this file in CMYK Color Space. I made several attempt to get this using Cocoa, unsuccessfully.

The closest I could get is to get the picture in CMYK, but it lost its transparency during the conversion. The transparency has been converted to white somehow.

Here is the code I used:

```
NSImage * sourceImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath.path];
NSBitmapImageRep * sourceImageRep = [[sourceImage representations] objectAtIndex:0];
NSColorSpace * targetColorSpace = [NSColorSpace genericCMYKColorSpace];
NSBitmapImageRep * targetImageRep = [sourceImageRep bitmapImageRepByConvertingToColorSpace:targetColorSpace
                                                                                   renderingIntent:NSColorRenderingIntentPerceptual];
NSData * data = [targetImageRep representationUsingType: NSTIFFFileType properties: nil];
[data writeToFile:finalPath.path atomically: NO];
```

Result: File converted to CMYK but the barcode lost its transparency.

Comment: Could the problem be the NSColorRenderingIntentPerceptual?

Comment: I thought the same, but I tried all different options and same result with all.

Comment: Oh, well, sorry about that... OK, let me try this — could be problem be the NSTIFFFileType? I've never seen a tiff with transparency. Maybe a PNG would work better?

Comment: Unfortunately, PNG only works with RGB Color Space, not CMYK.

Comment: So maybe what you're trying to do is impossible? I know nothing of CMYK (well, what I know I've managed to forget).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save NSView representation ignores transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604287/save-nsview-representation-ignores-transparency)

Comment: I managed to do it using ImageMagick :) But I wanted to be able to do it directly with Cocoa

Comment: In my opinion, converting to CMYK is generally not useful unless you're seeking to send an image directly to a printer -- where transparency will be irrelevant.  If the barcode is also in color, there is the additional complication that [conversions to and from CMYK are not trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088375/how-can-i-convert-rgb-to-cmyk-and-vice-versa-in-python/53110587#53110587) -- especially as there is "no meaning for CMYK colors that is as ubiquitous as sRGB is for RGB".